# Openstack Components not Fully Working

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I deployed openstack bundle using juju(version 2.6.9-bionic-amd64) and this tutorial https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/charm-deployment-guide/latest/install-openstack-bundle.html.

After deployment I found out ceph-osd and ceph-radosgw has status "blocked" and message "No block devices detected using current configuration". Can you please shed light on what the problem may be. Also, some other components such as "nova-compute" complain of "Incomplete relations: storage-backend". What do I need to do to rectify this? I have tried to install openstack by components, but this does not resolve it.
[image]

---